# redirect .htaccess - remove last part of url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need redirect url like: **www.domain.com/xx/yy/itinerar** to **www.domain.com/xx/yy**.
The value of yy can be various.
I have

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)itinerar
```

but i have trouble with RewriteRule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/itinerar/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: That's all I needed, thank you because I know Googlebot won't thank you!

Comment: I still have some problems with pages not found and I needed to rewrite all urls where www.mysite.com/empresa/em/empresa/any-coisa appears to www.mysite.com/empresa/any-coisa

and the other was to remove everything from /map/...
www.mysite.com/comercial-simocap/mapa/?str=Av+Raposo+Tavares,+19&cit=PIRACICABA&sta=S%C3%A3o+Paulo

Comment: @KarraMax: Can you please post a new question with all these requirements.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409350/how-to-remove-duplicate-and-unnecessary-part-in-a-url-using-htaccess-and-regex

Comment: This question should be asked on SO not on meta